# Getting data out of a cell with a #NAME? error in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I export data from another program into Excel and massage it with a macro.  I recently had a user get a crash because the text in the other program started with a hyphen.  It's a last name, and where I would usually expect "Smith" or some such, the value was "-Smith".  When exported to Excel, this was interpreted as an equation, and what was in the cell was "=-Smith".  Naturally, this displayed a #NAME? error.  When I tried to set a variable equal to that value, I got an error.

I can work around this by using the ISTEXT() function before assigning the cell contents to a variable.  However, what I'd like to do is get the data. As a test, on the worksheet I tried this:

'''=IF(ISTEXT(A2)=FALSE,MID(A2,3,20),A2)

You would think that this would grab the "Smith" portion of the contents of A2, but it doesn't. I've also tried:

'''=VALUETOTEXT(MID(A2,3,20))
'''=TEXTAFTER(A2,"-")

Nothing works.  I get #NAME? error for all of this.  If I click on the cell I can see the data I need, but I can't figure out how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need VBA, use `.Formula`:

```
Dim f As String
f = ActiveCell.Formula
```

Which you can then clean:

```
f = Replace(f, "=-", "")
```

If you need a worksheet formula, then use `FORMULATEXT`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=-","")
```

[image]